# update SQL and get error

Tags: c#, sql-server

hi i have many problem with update sql database from c# form

fisrt: i use this code for a button called "Update" that get values directly from text boxes and fill main sql server database.

```
SqlConnection cnt = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=db3;Integrated Security=True");
                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("update  phone set name=@name,lastname=@lastname,Phone=@Phone,Mobile=@Mobile,Area=@Area,date=@date", cnt);
                    cnt.Open(); 
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", namebox.Text); 
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lastname", lastbox.Text); 
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Phone", phonebox.Text); 
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Mobile", mobilebox.Text); 
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Area", areabox.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date", datestring); 
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();    
                    cnt.Close();
```

but it get error in mobile column :

`Violation of UNIQUE KEY constraint 'UQ__phone__5C7E359EA73D3013'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.phone'. The duplicate key value is (4802615).`

Note 2:  I am using this code for select and view selected row ready for edit

**1-Problem Solved the SQL column was Unique index so i removed that.**
**2- there wasn't a "where condition" so i fixed that too**

Comment: Where's your `WHERE` clause? If the table has more than one row this will always fail.

Comment: you have added a unique key constraint on the phone property. so if you will try to add the phone with existing one then it will throw this error.

Comment: yes table have many rows..  martin  but  i want too when user clicked a row that row go for edit and save or  get name  or id for editing directly with query like this codes.

Answer (score 2):

Where clause is not used so all the rows in the table are getting updated and hence the error is getting generated.

Answer (score 0):

Add a "WHERE Phone=@phone" and it's associated parameter command.   As the other person pointed out, you're updating but you haven't told the database to specifically focus on an individual record, so your command updates them all.

This is fine for the first record, as soon as it tries updating the second, it blows up because phone has a unique constraint on it, preventing any other record having the same data.   That's your error message.

You need to change your update statement to target the exact record you want to update.

Comment: i want to database to specifically focus on an individual record by selected row   or    a special text box for   record id or name.

Comment: Typically folks add an IDENTITY column to their table.   The dB takes care of its increment and uniqueness.  Then you can ditch the unique constraint on Phone, and your updates are like UPDATE FOR SET BAR='NERDS' WHERE CUSTOMERID=12335"

Comment: tnx all i found problem and fixed!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should set the PK or you update all the rows in the phone table. 
for example: UPDATE  tablename SET columName  WHERE  ....
I hope this will be useful

Comment: OP already has Unique on this column, and you want PK on phone column?